# Convergence of eigenvalues in Hilbert-Schmidt norm

Tags: spectral-theory, compact-operators

Suppose that $F$ and $F_n$ ($n \in \mathbb N$) are linear endomorphisms of a Hilbert space such that

- $F$ is Hilbert-Schmidt (i.e., compact),
- $F_n$ is finite rank for each $n$, and
- $F_n$ converges to $F$ in the Hilbert-Schmidt norm as $n → ∞$.

(I am *not* assuming self-adjointness anywhere.)

#### **True** or **false**?

The spectrum of $F_n$ converges to that of $F$ (e.g., in Hausdorff distance).

#### **Moreover,**

if it is true, can one deduce the (algebraic) multiplicity of each non-zero eigenvalue of $F$?

---

References most welcome! I know this appears similar to other related questions on convergence of spectra.

(I rooted around in a few FA books for such a result, but the results there focus on self-adjoint operators and don't mention compact operators.)

Comment: Compact and finite rank operators are not automorphisms in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!